# wget can't find url inside local file

Tags: wget

I have an `html` file.
page.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <img src="picture.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

But when i run `wget` as follows, it doesn't fetch the picture. Why? In the moment of execution, i am inside my home directory, while the page and the respective picture are inside `/tmp` directory.

```
wget -kF -i /tmp/page.html -B /tmp -A png
```

`wget output`:

```
No URLs found in /tmp/page.html.
Converted links in 0 files in 0 seconds.
```

Maybe it's a little bit easy, but i can't cope with it now.

Answer (score 0):

From `man wget`

```
       If this function is used, no URLs need be present on the command
       line.  If there are URLs both on the command line and in an input
       file, those on the command lines will be the first ones to be
       retrieved.  If --force-html is not specified, then file should
       consist of a series of URLs, one per line.
```

You have to specify `--force-html`

This will output the error message `/tmp/foo.html: Cannot resolve incomplete link picture.png.` as it's not a full URL, and relative URL's doesn't really make sense with a local file.

Comment: `-F` option is a short alternative to `--force-html`, and in the example above I use it. So, if `html` document uses relative links on the server it's being located, you say i can't download documents to which these relative links point? If I can instead, how can I do that?